# Очистить Кэш WebView

Tags: android

как очистить Кэш webview? Есть вроде метод "WebView.clearCache();" Но как им пользоваться?

Comment: В документации предельно ясно описан этот метод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но как им пользоваться?

Метод [`void clearCache (boolean includeDiskFiles)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearCache(boolean)) принимает параметр типа `boolean`, который обозначает:

> boolean: if false, only the RAM cache is cleared

Если Вы передаете `true`, то очищается весь кеш (в оперативной памяти и на диске), если `false` – то только в оперативной памяти.